# Why do you need to use require for the Set class?

Tags: ruby, data-structures, set, require

I'm using a set in my code and in order to create a new set using `Set.new` I have to `require 'set'` at the top of my file. It looks like the set class is part of Ruby's standard library, but if that's the case, why do you need to require it to use it?

Comment: The core is, more or less, built in. The standard library is just stuff that comes with Ruby but isn't available unless you ask for it. The [docs](http://ruby-doc.org) have them separated. That's about all we can say on the matter.

Comment: Oh, ok. Didn't realize the core and the standard library were different things. Thanks!

Comment: Even things like sqrt are not core and live in Math

Comment: @JLB `Math` is core, you do not need to require it.

Comment: Thanks for catching that, @CarySwoveland

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike the core modules, the modules in Ruby's standard library are not loaded by default. This is to minimize Ruby's memory footprint at runtime. Basically, if it's not in here http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/, then it needs to be `require`d at runtime.